# How to extend declared variables in lib.d.ts?

Tags: typescript

I just downloaded a javascript library called [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

Its a wrapper for history object in javascript to perform correct crossplatform functionality.

You can use it in a normal Javascript enviroment like this e.g. like this: History.pushState(data,title,url);

But i want to use it in a Typescript enviroment, and that means i have to declare the functions/variables in a d.ts file, but the History variable is already declared in the default lib.d.ts.

I can see it here (line 10475, 10485 & 16363):

```
interface History {
    length: number;
    state: any;
    back(distance?: any): void;
    forward(distance?: any): void;
    go(delta?: any): void;
    pushState(statedata: any, title?: string, url?: string): void;
    replaceState(statedata: any, title?: string, url?: string): void;
}

declare var History: {
    prototype: History;
    new (): History;
}

declare var history: History;
```

So now my question is how can i use the History.js library? What do i have to do to be able to write "History.pushState(data,title,url);" in Typescript?

I believe that i have to edit the "declare var History:{...}" to this (Correct me if i'm wrong):

```
declare var History: {
    prototype: History;
    new (): History;
    pushState(data: any, title: string, url: string): void;
}
```

And after that, i can now write History.pushState(...); in my Typescript code.

But i cant save the lib.d.ts file because it is protected. And its not that good even if i could save it, because then i can use the functions in other projects which might not have the History.js, and that would make an error (i believe the lib.d.ts is shared in all projects).

So how am i able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i just found out other people had made a Definitely Typed library, and they had the same problem, and made another way to solve it.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/history/history-tests.ts